# What is this for-loop supposed to do?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I've been trudging through some Javascript code and encountered this loop

```
for (var w = window; w.window === window.window.window; w = w.window) {
    w.w = w.prompt("Enter password");
    if (w.w === "swordfish") break;
    w.alert("Incorrect password.");
}
w.alert("Welcome, authenticated user!");
```

This code doesn't really make any sense to me. What in the world is going on here and how does it work?

Comment: it's saying "loop until password is swordfish". (what a long way to create a while(true) loop)

Comment: `while (1=0)`? Wouldn't that break immediately?

Comment: Where did you encounter this code, by the way? I hope that it's not the true authentication mechanism for the application :p

Comment: I was doing a code review for the next version of the Department of Justice website. ;p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`window` is always equal to `window.window....window`, so the loop will never end, unless the password is correct.

A `for(;;)` loop has the following signature:

```
for (init; test; increment);
```

It keeps continuing until `test` is false. Since `window === window` is always true, the loop keeps running, until `break` is encountered. For clarification, `w` always refers to `window`.

Comment: +1, but you're not explaining the part that I think the OP is most likely missing, which is that in an HTML environment, `window` is the global object, so all global variables are actually properties of `window`. For example, `window.alert` is the same as `alert`, and `window.window` and `window.window.window` are both the same as `window`.

Comment: +1 I was about to edit it, but then I saw your excellent comment.

Answer (score 2):

Well the alertbox keeps popping up for an indefinite period of time unless you provide the password "**swordfish**" !

If you encounter such script , Just disable JavaScript and view the Source , grab the password (make a note of it) , enable the JS , run the script again and enter the password to see what awaits ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to see the preceding line to fully understand this code:

```
var window = (function () { return this; })();
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would be much clearer if you instead used `var window = new (function() { this.window = window; })().window;`.